# ROS Answers SE migration: texas_park

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to find the packages for Texai robot, those were available few years ago, where are there now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48509/texas_park/) by [Harry](https://answers.ros.org/users/3616/harry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They're probably in one of the graveyard areas of the ros-pkg or wg-ros-pkg repositories.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1